# How to preload data when .net core webapi startup?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

About 900 thousand database records are used by some calculation,so I want to fill a datatable when webapi startup ,and the datatable can be used by some controller and method.
What's the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

> About 900 thousand database records are used by some calculation,so I want to fill a datatable when webapi startup ,and the datatable can be used by some controller and method.

If the database query and calculation would take long time to complete, you can try to implement a [hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) with background task logic, and cache caculation result in redis etc. Then you can get cached data from redis within your controller and method.

Besides, if query and calculation logic would be not very complex, you can try to create and implement a custom service for querying database and doing calculation, and [register your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) then use it within your controller.

Comment: You can check the doc to know how to register service in DI first and implement custom data accessing service based on database, ORM and actual requirement.